# What does KDE Discover do when upgrading package asks an interactive question?

Tags: kde, upgrade

When I run `apt upgrade`, some packages ask interactive questions, including fairly important ones, e.g. about overwriting user's configs.

If I run an upgrade like this from KDE Discover, what will happen? Some default answer silently submitted / upgrade skipped / UI dialog with the question shown / etc.?

Is this behavior configurable?

Does Discover have a clear documentation on this?